# C++14 digit separator messes up indentation

Tags: xcode, xcode7

In our company, we recently switched to the C++14 standard for our shared code base.
I wanted to take this the advantage of using the single quote character for separating thousands:

```
int a = 2'120'000;
```

But in Xcode 7.3.1, there is a problem with indentation. If there is an odd number of single quote characters inside function parentheses, the indentation engine wrongly assume the function call is not finished.

```
    double a = floor(1'234.78);
                     int b = 2; // <-- note wrong indentation here
```

Is there any workaround, other than not using this feature or putting extraneous (and unreadable) quotes to have a even number of them ?